# How to create dynamic link in views?

Tags: views, routes

I have created a page in Views, and the path is node/%/images. Now I want to put a dynamic link in the header. I want to link to http://www.example.com/node/add/album/[nid], where "[nid]" is the node ID of the node being viewed. How can I do this?

---

How do I add HTML tags to it? I want to make it as a image button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`arg(1)` would be your friend here. In your view header definition (PHP format) put something like:

```
print l(t('Add album'), 'node/add/album/' . arg(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Then you can do it like this

```
print "<a href='node/add/album" . arg(1) . "'>Add album</a>";
```

Comment: It is preferable to use `l()`.

Comment: yes but in his case he should use the anchor tag as he want to use img in the link so he will need the img tag which he can't use in the `l()`;

Comment: In [l()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/l/6) is clearly reported, "'html' (default FALSE): Whether $text is HTML or just plain-text. For example, to make an image tag into a link, this must be set to TRUE, or you will see the escaped HTML image tag." The same is true for Drupal 7.